# Using CosmosDB as SignalR pool

Tags: c#, signalr, azure-cosmosdb

I'm having problems with the stability of the pool in an Azure Function, as I described in this question, [Persist connection pool signalr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68201854/persist-connection-pool-signalr) , so I would like to know about the efficiency of using CosmosDB and the access speed, to be able to create an application that is really realtime.

I did some local testing and noticed that it took a long time to create and update the objects in the cosmos, I mean, a lot of time compared to simple memory access.

Comment: Can you share your code for creating/updating documents in Cosmos DB? Are you by any chance creating instances of `CosmosClient` on each request? That could be the reason for the long time.

Comment: @GauravMantri My code is exactly this the code of this tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/azure/cosmos-db/sql-api-get-started

Comment: Can you please share an English version of the link? Unfortunately my Portuguese is a bit rustic .

Comment: Gaurav, its the same as this. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-api-get-started

Comment: @GauravMantri, Sorry, I didn't realize I sent the link in Portuguese

Comment: @MarkBrown - Please correct me if I am wrong but the sample code will try to create Cosmos client every time it runs and that would result in long operation time. Right?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/manage-connections - If you are creating a client, please follow up the Functions best practices - you should have a static/singleton instance to be reused across executions.
Please post an example of your Function code.